# QGIS Path for layouts

Tags: qgis

I would like to know where (path on my pc) I can find saved layout-files for maps. The reason for that is that I would like to create specific layouts that i want to reuuse, save them on a central folder and then use these layouts from a central path in other QGIS-Projects.
I would be grateful for any advice!

Thanks
Jakob

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find information about how to find the path of the templates in your system: [The Print Layout Manager](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/overview_composer.html#id1).

Here is another option [Layouts Settings in QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#id12).